# What does fantasy-land/id do?

Tags: javascript, category-theory, fantasyland

```
fantasy-land/id :: Category c => () -> c a a
```

I don't really understand what this signature says? `id` is a method that takes zero parameters and returns something that is a Category and two other things.

Is that correct? What's the point of this?

Answer (score 2):

A category consists of objects and morphisms (arrows). If you want to define a category inside Haskell, you pretty much are stuck with objects as types. But for any two objects you may define a set of morphisms: the hom-set. Here, `c` is a type constructor that takes two objects (types), say `a` and `b` and produces a hom-set `c a b`. In the simplest example just replace `c` with `(->)`. In this case `c a b` becomes `a->b` (using infix notation). By the same token `c a a` corresponds to `a->a`. One of these morphisms is designated as the identity morphism. The function `() -> c a a` picks that morphism. The complete definition must also include the composition operator `(.)` that takes two composable hom-sets and produces a third, and the laws. Unit and associativity laws are not expressible in Haskell, though.

Comment: I thank you for your answer but for somebody who isn't deep into this stuff this is really hard to understand.